# Is the expression '1/4 of something' or '3/4 of something' idiomatic/natural sounding?

Tags: phrase-usage, articles

Say, I have a packet of milk and there is not much left in it. If I pour it in a cup, it might less than 1/4 filled.

Can I describe it like this

> There is less than **one fourth of a cup** of milk in the packet.

Or in another context

> The amount of juice in the box will be slightly more than **three fourth of a cup**.

Also, should I use a or the with cup? one fourth of a cup or one fourth of the cup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your statements are fine. (just change *three fourth* to *three fourths*)

You should use "a cup". *cup* in this context is a general reference to a measurement. It is the same for everyone.

> He drove on for half **a mile**.

You could use *the* if you were referring to a specific cup, though.

> There was enough juice to fill three fourths of **the cup.**

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically correct to say one fourth of the cup.  We are using "the" to refer to a specific cup.

Similarly, it's OK to say three fourths, not fourth, of the cup. We can also use one quarter and three quarters instead.